# How to get the status of a message sent with nodemailer that never reach the recipient?

Tags: email, smtp, nodemailer

I am trying to use *nodemailer* to send emails via a mail server that I own in JustHost. I am using the SMTP settings provided by the hosting.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.wegocuba.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: PROVIDERS.wegocuba.user,
        pass: PROVIDERS.wegocuba.pass 
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

let configureMailer = (text, to) => {
    return {
        from: '"USER" <user@wegocuba.com>',
        to: to, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello world',
        text: text,
    };
};
mySendMail = (to, text) => {
    let sender = configureMailer(text, to);
    transporter.sendMail(sender, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(info.messageId);
    });
},
```

When I call the **mySendMail(to, text)** function, the server respond without problems.

```
{  accepted: [ 'myemail@gmail.com' ],
   rejected: [],
   envelopeTime: 107,
   messageTime: 73,
   messageSize: 288,
   response: '250 OK id=1eUGz4-003LtQ-RK',
   envelope: { from: 'user@wegocuba.com', to: [ 'myemail@gmail.com' ] },
   messageId: '<9efa8726-6d8b-2161-36d5-023b49799871@wegocuba.com>' }
```

But the email never reach the recipient, neither appears as sent in the SENT folder. 
How can I know what really is happening in the mail server?

Comment: did you find the solution for this??